# How to download from google cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Is google cloud storage badly designed; or am i missing something really obvious; or is it made for techies?

I'm not a techie.

I uploaded files to google cloud storage, and I want to download some of them to a different computer. How do I download files from there?

Comment: Are you talking about [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-storage) or [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/)? The former is for developers, the latter is for consumers.

Comment: Cloud Storage in Google Cloud Console

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems you are having trouble downloading the files from Google Cloud Storage.

You should be able to right click on the filename when you are in Cloud Storage and click 'Save Link As' and that should allow you to download your file. That's about it.

This is what that the file front end looks like just in case you are somewhere else or referring to a different product:
[image: A file on Cloud Storage]

Comment: Thanks Daniel. It looks like cmd-click on Mac. I was thinking I'd be able to download folders and their contents; I guess maybe that's not the case. But I'll manage just downloading individual files.

Comment: @Richard: If your primary use case is uploading and downloading files and folders by hand, the product you probably want to use is Google Drive, which is much better suited for personal use. Bonus: it's free for up to 15 gigabytes of stuff and then pretty cheap after that.

Comment: for me, left clicking and "Save file" worked, but right clicking didn't. (.tgz file)

Comment: Does anyone know what using `wget` or `curl` mangles the file when downloading from the specified link?  Using the download option works fine however.....

Answer (score 37):

If you have it in a bucket, you can use [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil). Just install gsutil on your local machine (for example by installing the Google Cloud SDK) and then run something like

`gsutil cp gs://my-bucket/my-file .`

Answer (score 8):

`http://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket>/<object>`

For example, if you uploaded `foo.zip` into bucket `myBucket`, you can download it with

`http://storage.googleapis.com/myBucket/foo.zip`

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Download gcloud sdk first and then write

`gsutil cp -r gs://bucketname  local_folder_path`

This will download entire directory

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to use the browser to download files, you should navigate to [cloud.google.com/console](http://cloud.google.com/console), select the appropriate project and then "Cloud Storage" on the left. That will display a list of buckets to click on, from where the individual objects are available for download.

It's also worth noting, though, that the Cloud Console is really just a convenience; Google Cloud Storage, like other enterprise cloud solutions, is designed around API usage. Google Cloud Storage also offers the [gsutil tool](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) that makes the full functionality of these APIs available through a convenient command line interface.

Comment: I can navigate to the file I want to download no problem. It's downloading it that I'm having difficulty with. Any folder or file I navigate to, has a checkbox by it. So I check the box, but I see no 'download' button. If I drag and drop, it turns into a .webloc file, and if I take the .webloc extension off the file name, some files don't open in their original format

Comment: As noted above, right-clicking on files and selecting "Save as" will do the trick, as should simply left clicking files.

Answer (score 3):

The right click method didn't work for me, here is what worked:

**Step 1:** install gsutil on your local machine: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install?hl=fr

**Step 2:** copy files from bucket to your local machine running the command: `gsutil cp [-r if repository] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME] [OBJECT_DESTINATION_IN_LOCAL]`

Comment: Happy it helped!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a VM instance running, you could use **scp** to transfer files. The following worked for me:

```
   scp username@external-ip-address:/path/to/file/on/remote/VM local/path/
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Install Google SDK Console in your Computer
Ref : https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install

Step 2:
Google Cloud Command to Download Entire Bucket into Local Directory

Syntax :

```
> gsutil cp -r gs://[bucketName]/ [locaDir]
```

Example:

```
gsutil cp -r gs://abc/ C:\Users\amol.jadhav\cloud
```

*Note: Make sure that you have sufficient permission to create folder/files in local directory*

Answer (score 0):

download the Cloud CLI and setup your project with project id
[download link](https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/GoogleCloudSDKInstaller.exe)

use the below code to copy images from a firebase folder to your local computer

```
 syntax: gsutil cp -r gs://[bucketName]/ [locaDir]
    Example1:gsutil cp -r gs://bucketname/ C:\Users\username\cloud
    Example2 for multiple downloads:gsutil -m cp -r gs://appId.appspot.com/userProfileImages "E:\Images"
```

<sub>**Note**:see your cloud bucket->https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser?authuser=2&project=firebaseAppName&prefix=

change firebaseAppName(or select from select project option from the top)
with your firebase app name.</sub>